# How to set maximum field width for a std::string with iomanip?

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream

`std::setw()` sets the minimum field width for all output, and `std::setprecision()` is capable of affecting floats, but is there a way to set the maximum field width for a `std::string`, to achieve the same result as the following `printf()` format specifier: `%10.10s`

I am aware that `boost::format` may be capable of doing this, but I am looking for a solution that is strictly C++ standards only, no third party software.

Comment: "no third party software" - *strictly speaking*, your standard library implementation is also "third party software" unless you work for whomever wrote it 

Comment: Once they standardzie the `fmt` proposal you can use that. Until then you might want to check out [fmt](http://fmtlib.net/latest/). For string, wouldn't `substr(n)` do what you want? As in: `std::string x = "Hello this is a very long string"; std::cout << x.substr(10) << '\n';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to do this with C++ streams.  One way to do this is to use a `std::string_view` to just get the slice that you want like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

std::string_view print_max(std::string_view sv, std::size_t width)
{
    return sv.substr(0, width);
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << print_max("0123456789", 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << print_max("0123456789", 5) << "\n";
    std::cout << print_max("0123456789", 8) << "\n";
    std::cout << print_max("0123456789", 20);
}
```

Output:

```
012
01234
01234567
0123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
std::string string_w(char *c_str, int width)
{
    int pad = width - strlen(c_str);
    return (std::string(c_str) + std::string(pad > 0 ? pad : 0, ' ')).substr(0,width);
}
```